# Trying to connect Django to MySQL. Connection error when migrating (Xampp, Linux)

Tags: mysql, django, sockets, connection

I've been working for several weeks on Django. So far I have made 2 small projects. Now I tried to connect Django to the MySQL database.

1. First, I started a new project.
2. Then made a new app and updated the app in settings.py.
3. After that I changed the database in the same file settings.py with my settings.
4. Made a small model (in the file models.py).
5. Installed all the necessary apps, (pip install) mysqlclient etc,
6. Made the first migration successfully with
   `python manage.py makemigrations`
   So far so good!

Next, I tried to make the second migration (`python manage.py migrate`), as in the instructions.

Then the error message appears:

> 'error 111, can't connect to database'

Made some changes in the settings file, including SQL mode `strict_trans_tables`.

Now it shows me the error:

> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket ... Missing file .../mysql.sock.

I looked up the directory and there was no such file.

In the file my.cnf the filename and path is different!!! And exists! (It is using this existing file in my.cnf, but after executing the commang `migrate` it is searching for this file in a place, where it does not exist!)

To clarify things a little bit, the exact message of the error:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")

There is no such file in the current directory (as I have checked).

my.cnf file contains the following path and filename:
`socket=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock`
There is a file in the current directory. MySQL works, as well.

What is going on and what to do?

=================================

Since my issue has been resolved, I how start thinking about what could cause such issue in the first place!

Apparently Django didn't know the path to the my.cnf file, even if it exists, so it had to be implemented manually from the settings.py file with the short code I have written below.

Recently I have been working on a similar projects, involving usage of javascript and node.js as a mean to create a website with access to database from mysql of the Xampp. I am using Linux for both projects, thus it might be related to the specifications of the system. Again in the node.js project I had to implement manually the path to the socked file, as follows:

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
// THE PATH TO THE SOCKET FILE:
    socketPath: process.env.DB_SOCKET_PATH 
});
```

And thus I stated wondering why this issue has happened in the first place?? As I said, I could only suppose it might be related to the Linux version I am using (Linux Mint 20.3), or the way it was installed. When you start working with computers it is much easier to know what caused the problem, rather than only the correct solution.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I checked so many times the settings.py file, so there is not possible to be a problem there!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the Django project was able to start using the MySQL database!!!

The changes in the file setting.py are the same as before, as follows:

```
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'django_db',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
```

the only thing that had to be done in addition to this, was to include the path of file my.cnf manually:

```
        'OPTIONS': {
            'read_default_file': '/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf',
        },
```

Obviously, this was the reason in the first place the path to the socket file to be mistaken.

*But why in the first place this error occurs, I don't know. Perhaps somewhere after the installation some other path was given, but I don't know where is this path, pointing to other directory of the socket file separately, or to other path for the my.cnf file.*

With the PostgreSQL database the connection was made so simply, it required only the 1st changes in the settings.py file.

After that, additional migrations were made without any disturbance, as well as the superuser account.

The source website from which I was able to use as a cheat sheet for the complete process:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-django-app-and-connect-it-to-a-database

Answer (score 1):

You have reached an issue which suggests a MySQL problem. It is wise to try and connect to MySQL directly at this point, because if that's successful, then you know for sure that your issues are on the application settings' side and if it's unsuccessful, then you need to solve MySQL's connectivity first and only then switch to your app's settings.

Now, the error clearly suggests that MySQL's socket file cannot be found.

First, let's check whether MySQL is running at all. In Ubuntu Linux the command to do so is

```
sudo service mysql status
```

If you use something else as an OS, then of course you will need to operate slightly differently.

In Ubuntu, if the command above yields something like

> Unit mysql.service could not be found.

, then the service does not exist and you need to install it.

Otherwise, if the service exists but is not running, then you will need to start it if you are able. If not, then you have some maintenance to do.

Finally, if the MySQL service is successfully running, try connecting to it via cli, like:

```
mysql -u <youruser> -p
```

The `-p` at the end signifies that a password will be used, so after running the command above you will need to type in the password (if everything goes well).

If you get the same socket file-related error (which presumably will happen), then you will need to find the location of the socket file (**.sock**) and update MySQL's cnf file (**/etc/my.cnf** in Linux) so that it will take into account the correct location of the socket file:

```
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: Yes, I have done everything you have written so far. As I said, the filename and path in the /etc/my.cnf is correct, thus there is no need to be changed. However, the error shows,that the file it tried to open is different and, again as I said doesn't exist. I am talking about the migration procedure. The first one is correctly performed. The second gives the current error.

Comment: @MarkoKolaksazov I would still look for the file, because it's possible that there are multiple sock files and the one you see is not necessarily in use. I would also look at the privileges of the user running your app to reach the location of the sock file. However, what you absolutely need to do is to try and connect to MySQL directly. If you do so, then you will get a meaningful information even if you cannot connect to it.

Comment: The file MySQL.sock is in the same directory, as it is said in the pathway in /etc/my.cnf file. When I ran the command 'migrate' it showed that error, saying 'I am looking for the file elsewhere'.

Comment: By the way, is it a problem if I run the command ```sudo /opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root -p``` it runs ONLY with the directory path?

Comment: @MarkoKolaksazov this is why you needed to test it with CLI. If it runs only with directory path AND sudo, then you have two problems: 1. MySQL cannot be referred as `mysql` (without the path), you need to create a symlink, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/427818/how-to-run-scripts-without-typing-the-full-path. 2. Your app user is likely not a sudoer, so you will need to do some `chmod` work as well.

Comment: I am sorry, I was writing from my phone. Django is new to me, as well as xampp. The status shows it is running, without details. By the way this command again is executing in a different way, so I guess a different way of installing. And when I execute it your way it says, ```Unit mysql.service could not be found.```, but I didn't know it was so important. Please don't be confused, The MySQL service is running, but with different command.

Comment: No worries. Based on what you say it very much seems that the issue is that MySQL cannot be run as itself, a symlink is missing as well as probably some privileges as well. Please look into the link I have given in my previous comment, it might lead you to the solution. Also, if my answer contributed to a solution, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: No, the same mistake. I also tried running the first makemigrations command and it shows no changes (as expected), but this time with the same error. Is it possible something occurred, when I restarted the computer after the unsuccessful migration??

Comment: @MarkoKolaksazov if the error is telling you that `mysql.service` could not be found, then you can only reach MySQL using the full path or the user who want to use it with has no privileges to the service. Can you successfully run `sudo mysql -u root -p` without specifying the path?

Comment: Yes, now the command runs successfully without the ```sudo```, and without the directory path

Comment: It is really frustrating, how easily things can break after the following 'successful' installation. This is very much true about Linux. I had different problems with MySQL in the past, but solved them after much reading (and re-installation of Linux)

Comment: @MarkoKolaksazov so, now cli-based MySQL usage works, but you still get a "mysql.service not found" when you tryto connect MySQL from the app? Is this the current status?

Comment: Yes, I get exactly the same message, when I try to check the status of mysql.service with your command.

Comment: @MarkoKolaksazov on CLI?

Comment: I write the following: ```$ sudo lampp start```; It shows the Apache2 -> OK, MySQL -> OK; ProFTPD -> OK; After that, ```$ sudo systemctl status mysql```; The answer is : ```mysql.service could not be found```; phpmyadmin opens, etc. ```sudo service mysql status``` shows the same error.

Comment: I left MySQL behind and installed PostgreSQL instead (and connected to Django). It works perfectly!

Comment: @MarkoKolaksazov the issue was that the service was not found by the OS. But I'm glad the issue was solved.